# Differential Geometry : Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that A regular curve between two points $p,q$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with minimal length is necessarily the line segment from $p$ to $q$

Comment: Find a shorter way...

Comment: I can't understand this problem ! But I think that It wants to find a regular curve

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for a **proof** of this fact ?

Comment: I only say that

Comment: Hint : Consider the Schwarz inequality $\left\langle{X,Y}\right\rangle\le\left\|X\right\|\cdot\left\|Y\right\|$ for the tangent vector and the difference vector $p-q$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You may benefit from reading [this Help Center page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). At least you may better understand why users voted to put your question on hold after reading that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is demonstrated by the calculation of the variations that in Euclidee geometries, or of type $ \mathbb{R}^n\ $  , the minimum length curve that joins two points is "the segment". I emphasize that this result is not valid in non-Euclidean geometries as originally demonstrated by Gauss.